# Using a PHP/HTML form to insert information into 2 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

Using a form I am inserting the information from 3 text fields and 2 checkboxes into a MySQL database.

The database consists of 2 tables with the following rows:

```
id - articletitle - articleorganization - articledate - articleurl

id - article_tags - articlid - tagid
```

The checkboxes use an array and are coded thus:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="geology" id="articletags_0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="astronomy" id="articletags_1" />
```

And the MySQL statement looks like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
 articleorganization='$articleorganization',
 articledate='$articledate',
 articleurl='$articleurl' ")

mysql_query2("INSERT INTO articles_tags SET articletags='$articletags' ")
```

However, when I visit the page in a web browser it shows a blank page.

In case anyone is wondering, the reason I'm using checkboxes is because the articles will need to be tagged with a combination of tags, and this will ensure that consistency is used in the tagging. Also, I have a form used to edit the articles, and the database structure could, I believe, be used to make the checkboxes "checked" on the edit page.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: enable error reporting in php.ini http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php , it will print the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank page is actually from a syntax error. To see syntax errors, edit the php.ini or add this line to the top of your code `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Change `mysql_query2()` to `mysql_query()`

Your SQL sytax is incorrect...

If the data is already in the database you want to use UPDATE.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
 articleorganization='$articleorganization',
 articledate='$articledate',
 articleurl='$articleurl' ");

mysql_query("UPDATE articles_tags SET articletags='$articletags' ")
```

This is how you insert data:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles (articletitle,
 articleorganization,
 articledate,
 articleurl) VALUES ($articletitle,$articleorganization,$articledate,$articleurl) ");
```

**Note**: You should use `mysql_error()` to check for syntax errors.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles_tags SET articletags='$articletags' ") OR DIE(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

what is mysql_query2 ? are you sure you put semicolon after query ?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles_tags SET articletags='$articletags' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `mysql_query2('*******)` to `mysql_query()` and enable your error reporting to check error comes in the code. Echo your query and run directly in database to check any SQL related error.